# FIndParent Error- Cannot navigate to dynamic member

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am passing a dynamic variable (a list of elements) and looping through the item. The issue of `Cannot navigate to dynamic member` arising when I'm trying to interact with the items.

```
public void definePositions()
{ 
    var positions = PanelPositionsContent.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[class='cell cell-id-symbol']"));            
    CheckEntryPrice(positions);
}


private void CheckEntryPrice(dynamic positions)
{
    foreach (var position in positions)
    {
        if (position.Text.ToLower().Equals(ScenarioContext.Current["symbol"].ToString().ToLower()))
        {
            CommonMethods.Log("Successfully: " + ScenarioContext.Current["symbol"]);
        }

        if (position.FindParent().FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class='cell cell-id-price']")).Text.Equals(ScenarioContext.Current["price"]))
        {
            CommonMethods.Log("Failing test, : " + ScenarioContext.Current["price"] + ", actual price" +
                positions[0].FindParent().FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class='cell cell-id-price']")).Text);
            Assert.Fail("Price is not correct");
        }

        CommonMethods.Log("Passed test, clicked price matches position price: expected price: " + ScenarioContext.Current["price"] + ", actual price: " +
                          positions[0].FindParent().FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class='cell cell-id-price']")).Text);
    }//calaculate points from curr price to entry

    CheckGross();
}
```

What could be the issue, should I define `dynamic positions` instead of passing it in?

Answer (score 0):

An IWebElement has no method named `FindParent()`. But if you are using an extension method, asserts that you're *using* the extension's namespace;

If you have no extension method, you need to get the parent this way:

```
yourIWebElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".."))
```

Or you can create the extension method:

```
public static IWebElement FindParent(this IWebElement e, int parentLevel = 1)
{
    return (e == null || parentLevel <= 0)
            ? e
            : e.FindElement(By.XPath("..")).FindParent(--parentLevel);
}
```